# How to remove white areas inside matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Error in matplotlib.pyplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63I2k.png)
I am plotting a heat diagramm of a plate. when i put similar lengths in x and y axis everything is ok. However if i put length o x axis 150 and length of y axis 1 then there are some white spots inside. printing Temp2d i see that there are the correct values inside. for the plate i take that bottom and left side are insulated and up and right sides have temperature of Tn and Te respectively.

```
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import solve

#info
Tn=None
Te=None
Lx=None
Ly=None
N=None
while Tn==None or Te==None or Lx==None or Ly==None or N==None:
        try:
                Tn=int(input('Temperature at north side='))
                Te=int(input('Temperature at east side='))
                Lx=int(input('Length of x axis='))
                Ly=int(input('Length of y axis='))
                N=int(input('Minimum nodes per side='))
        except ValueError:
                print("Not an integer value.")

start_time=time.time()


if Ly<Lx:
        Ny=N
        Ygrid=np.linspace(0,Ly,Ny)
        dY=Ygrid[1]-Ygrid[0]
        dX=dY
        Nx=Lx/dX+1
        Nx=int(Nx)
        print('Nx=',Nx,'Ny=',Ny)
        Xgrid=np.linspace(0,Lx,Nx)
        dX=Xgrid[1]-Xgrid[0]
else:
        Nx=N
        Xgrid=np.linspace(0,Lx,Nx)
        dX=Xgrid[1]-Xgrid[0]
        dY=dX
        Ny=Ly/dY+1
        Ny=int(Ny)
        print('Nx=',Nx,'Ny=',Ny)
        Ygrid=np.linspace(0,Ly,Ny)
        dY=Ygrid[1]-Ygrid[0]
print('dX=',dX,'dY=',dY)

Snodes=Nx*Ny
print('Total Nodes=',Snodes)

Xnodes=np.zeros((2,Snodes)) 
for j in range (0,Ny):
        for i in range (0, Nx):
                node=j*Nx+i
                Xnodes[0,node]=i*dX
                Xnodes[1,node]=j*dY
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(Xnodes[0],Xnodes[1],marker='.',ls='-')
plt.show(block=False)


A=np.zeros((Snodes,Snodes))
B=np.zeros(Snodes)


##External Nodes

#Adiabetic Walls
i=0 #node=j*Nx+i=j*Nx
for j in range (0,Ny-1):
        node=j*Nx
        nodep1=j*Nx+1
        A[node,node]=1
        A[node,nodep1]=-1

j=0 #node=j*Nx+i=i
for i in range (1,Nx-1):
        node=i
        nodep1=Nx+i
        A[node,node]=1
        A[node,nodep1]=-1

#Dirchlet
i=Nx-1
for j in range (0,Ny-1):
        node=j*Nx+i
        A[node,node]=1
        B[node]=Te

j=Ny-1
for i in range (0,Nx-1):
        node=j*Nx+i
        A[node,node]=1
        B[node]=Tn

#Node between Te and Tn side
A[Nx*Ny-1,Nx*Ny-1]=1
B[Nx*Ny-1]=(Te+Tn)/2


##Internal Nodes

for i in range (1,Nx-1):
        for j in range (1,Ny-1):
                node=j*Nx+i
                nodeip1=j*Nx+i+1
                nodeim1=j*Nx+i-1
                nodejp1=(j+1)*Nx+i
                nodejm1=(j-1)*Nx+i
                A[node,node]+=-2/dX**2-2/dY**2
                A[node,nodeip1]+=1/dX**2
                A[node,nodeim1]+=1/dX**2
                A[node,nodejp1]+=1/dY**2
                A[node,nodejm1]+=1/dY**2


#Temperature

Temp= solve(A, B)

Temp2d=np.zeros((Ny,Nx))
for j in range (0,Ny):
        for i in range (0,Nx):
                node=j*Nx+i
                Temp2d[j,i]=Temp[node]

colorinterpolation = 50
colourMap = plt.cm.jet
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
cp=ax.contourf(Xgrid,Ygrid,Temp2d,colorinterpolation, cmap=colourMap)
fig.colorbar(cp)
plt.title("Contour of Temperature")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
plt.show(block=False)


end_time=time.time()-start_time
print('Total time:')
print(end_time)
```

Comment: Could you supply some typical values for the variables for which your plot doesn't produce the expected result?

Comment: In my example I'm inserting TN=100 te=0 LX=150 and Ly=1. I'm running the code in shell python 3.8.1 and in Jupiter with the same results.

Comment: When `Lx=150` and `Ly=1` you are representing an extremely narrow surface. When it is displayed, it is deformed to be almost square, filling the plot area. To have things displayed with the real ratios, use `ax.set_aspect('equal')`. But try this first with some less extreme example (e.g. `Lx=50` and `Ly=20`).